# Native library (.so file) not found in resource path

Tags: android

I have library and I try to add my android application which is named 'abc' so I create new folder

|-app

|-|-src

|-|-|-main

|-|-|-|-jniLibs

|-|-|-|-|-android-aarch64

|-|-|-|-|-|-abc.so

and I added .so file here but when I try to run application it gives me this error

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native library (android-aarch64/abc.so) not found in resource path (.)
```

I don't know why, I already checked other relative issues but didn't help me

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In my problem I checked my apk from android studio -> build -> analyze apk and I found 'arm64-v8a' folder was empty, so I understand I have to put so file under the arm64-v8a folder. I put the abc.so file under the arm64-v8a folder and my error gone

I hope it works for you all.